# How to run background service running even if application process stopped in Android 10?

Tags: android, service, background-service

I need to run a service that will be alive after I close application. The service will be started from launcher activity. How can I disable this service from the launcher activity?

This is my Service class written in Kotlin:

```
class LockerService: Service() {
    private val screenUnlockedBroadcastReceiver = ScreenUnlockedBroadcastReceiver()
    private val taskPausedBroadcastReceiver = TaskPausedBroadcastReceiver()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null;
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("LockerService", "Created")
        registerReceiver(screenUnlockedBroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            registerReceiver(taskPausedBroadcastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(TaskPausedBroadcastReceiver.TASK_PAUSED),
                RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        } else {
            registerReceiver(taskPausedBroadcastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(TaskPausedBroadcastReceiver.TASK_PAUSED))
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(screenUnlockedBroadcastReceiver)
        unregisterReceiver(taskPausedBroadcastReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }
}
```

I start the service from the activity like this:

```
                val serviceIntent = Intent(this, LockerService::class.java)
                serviceIntent.addFlags(Service.START_STICKY)
                startService(serviceIntent)
```

Comment: If your service is not foreground it does not elevate your app status and will get killed alongside the process when user swipes it from recents. You cannot have a permanent "background" services since oreo.

Comment: Pawel, so I must make service foreground? How can I do it?